# How to get the balance from 2 sql's?

Tags: sql, firebird

Table: ProductRequisitionNumber

| ProductRequisitionNumber | Date |
| --- | --- |
| PRN001 | 01/01/11 |
| PRN002 | 02/01/11 |
| PRN003 | 03/01/11 |
| PRN004 | 04/01/11 |
| PRN005 | 05/01/11 |

Table: ProductRequisitionDetail

| ID | ProductRequisitionNumber | ProductCode | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRN001 | PDC001 | 100 |
| 2 | PRN002 | PDC001 | 100 |
| 3 | PRN002 | PDC002 | 200 |
| 4 | PRN003 | PDC001 | 100 |
| 5 | PRN003 | PDC002 | 200 |
| 6 | PRN003 | PDC003 | 300 |
| 7 | PRN004 | PDC001 | 100 |
| 8 | PRN004 | PDC002 | 200 |
| 9 | PRN004 | PDC003 | 300 |
| 10 | PRN004 | PDC004 | 400 |
| 11 | PRN005 | PDC001 | 100 |
| 12 | PRN005 | PDC002 | 200 |
| 13 | PRN005 | PDC003 | 300 |
| 14 | PRN005 | PDC004 | 400 |
| 15 | PRN005 | PDC005 | 500 |

Table: PurchaseOrderNumber

| PurchaseOrderNumber | Date |
| --- | --- |
| PON001 | 01/01/11 |
| PON002 | 02/01/11 |
| PON003 | 03/01/11 |
| PON004 | 04/01/11 |
| PON005 | 05/01/11 |
| PON006 | 06/01/11 |
| PON007 | 07/01/11 |
| PON008 | 08/01/11 |
| PON009 | 09/01/11 |
| PON010 | 10/01/11 |
| PON011 | 11/01/11 |
| PON012 | 12/01/11 |
| PON013 | 01/01/12 |
| PON014 | 02/01/12 |
| PON015 | 03/01/12 |

Table: PurchaseOrderDetail

| ID | PurchaseOrderNumber | ProductRequisitionNumber | ProductCode | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PON001 | PRN001 | PDC001 | 100 |
| 2 | PON002 | PRN002 | PDC001 | 50 |
| 3 | PON003 | PRN002 | PDC002 | 100 |
| 4 | PON004 | PRN003 | PDC001 | 50 |
| 5 | PON005 | PRN003 | PDC002 | 100 |
| 6 | PRN003 | PRN003 | PDC003 | 150 |
| 7 | PRN004 | PRN004 | PDC001 | 50 |
| 8 | PRN004 | PRN004 | PDC002 | 100 |
| 9 | PRN004 | PRN004 | PDC003 | 150 |
| 10 | PRN004 | PRN004 | PDC004 | 200 |
| 11 | PRN005 | PRN005 | PDC001 | 50 |
| 12 | PRN005 | PRN005 | PDC002 | 100 |
| 13 | PRN005 | PRN005 | PDC003 | 150 |
| 14 | PRN005 | PRN005 | PDC004 | 200 |
| 15 | PRN005 | PRN005 | PDC005 | 250 |

Result: (Quantity balance of ProductRequisitionNumber PRN001 and ProductCode PDC001 = 0)

| ProductRequisitionNumber | ProductCode | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PRN002 | PDC001 | 50 |
| PRN002 | PDC002 | 100 |
| PRN003 | PDC001 | 50 |
| PRN003 | PDC002 | 100 |
| PRN003 | PDC003 | 150 |
| PRN004 | PDC001 | 50 |
| PRN004 | PDC002 | 100 |
| PRN004 | PDC003 | 150 |
| PRN004 | PDC004 | 200 |
| PRN005 | PDC001 | 50 |
| PRN005 | PDC002 | 100 |
| PRN005 | PDC003 | 150 |
| PRN005 | PDC004 | 200 |
| PRN005 | PDC005 | 250 |

How can I get the remaining quantity of ProductRequition and ProductCode after issuing PurChaseOrder's (sql1 - sql2)?

SQL query #1:

```
SELECT 
    "ProductRequisitionNumber"."ProductRequisitionNumber", 
    "ProductRequisitionDetail"."ProductCode", 
    "ProductRequisitionDetail"."Quantity" 
FROM 
    "ProductRequisitionDetail", "ProductRequisitionNumber" 
WHERE 
    "ProductRequisitionDetail"."ProductRequisitionNumber" = "ProductRequisitionNumber"."ProductRequisitionNumber" 
ORDER BY  
    "ProductRequisitionNumber"."ProductRequisitionNumber" ASC, 
    "ProductRequisitionDetail"."ProductCode" ASC
```

SQL query #2:

```
SELECT 
    "PurchaseOrderNumber"."PurchaseOrderNumber", 
    "PurchaseOrderDetail"."ProductRequisitionNumber", 
    "PurchaseOrderDetail"."ProductCode", 
    "PurchaseOrderDetail"."Quantity" 
FROM 
    "PurchaseOrderNumber", "PurchaseOrderDetail" 
WHERE 
    "PurchaseOrderNumber"."PurchaseOrderNumber" = "PurchaseOrderDetail"."PurchaseOrderNumber" 
ORDER BY 
    "PurchaseOrderNumber"."PurchaseOrderNumber" ASC, 
    "PurchaseOrderDetail"."ProductRequisitionNumber" ASC, 
    "PurchaseOrderDetail"."ProductCode" ASC
```

How can I get the remaining quantity of ProductRequition and ProductCode after issuing PurChaseOrder's (sql1 - sql2)?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: I assume that fourth table should "PurchaseOrderDetail", not "PurchaseOrderNumber".

Comment: Can there be more than one purchase order against a product requisition? If so, what is the expected result? Also, here is a dbfiddle with the setup as shown in the question: https://dbfiddle.uk/EzxDp5Xj

Comment: Your overly complicated solution won't give correct results for products without purchases. Simple LEFT JOIN query should give better results, eg based on @MarkRotteveel's fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/ks6L8VX_